# System.Timers.Timer does not raise event properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I want to have some delay between some action (doing something); actions and delays stored in DB and will executed by order. for each item in DB, if it is action (`ItemType==1`), it will executed and if it is delay, it calculate time of event raise and when event raised, again with `schedule()` method, next item will proceed.

```
private int orderId=0;
private List<Timer> activeTimers=new List<Timer>();
public void schedule()
{
    var seqItem = seq.SequenceItem.OrderBy(i => i.OrderId).First(o => o.OrderId > orderId);
    orderId = seqItem.OrderId;
    if (seqItem.ItemType == 1)
    {
        var action = seqItem.Action;
        DeviceFile.switchDev(action.Device.Name, action.FinalState);//do action
        schedule();
    }
    else if (seqItem.ItemType == 4)//item is delay
        delay(seqItem.Delay);

}
private void delay(Delay delay)
{
     var timer = new Timer(delay.Duration.TotalMilliseconds);
     timer.AutoReset = false;
     timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
     timer.Start();
     activeTimers.Add(timer);
}
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    activeTimers.Remove((Timer)sender);
    ((Timer)sender).Dispose();
    schedule();
}
```

When I test these codes with ordered items of *action,delay,action*, no exception occurs  but third action does not execute(execute code til `var action=...` but `DeviceFile.switchDev` line does not execute!(on debug as you can see in below image, by *continuing* breakpoint, it shows me my main form and does not execute second line of `if`=> `DeviceFile.switchDev` line)).

[image]

Comment: And there is no exceptions? It is hard to believe that assignment is failing (also `Action` could be reading DB or have some other surprising code in the property)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no exception! `Action` is action of that item (from DB using EF).

Comment: You really *do* have an exception.  Using try/catch in an Elapsed event handler is a rock-hard requirement.  System.Timers.Timer is pretty awful, it swallows all exceptions, the debugger won't give a peep other than a "First chance" exception notification in the Output window.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox to debug your code.  Do consider using System.Threading.Timer instead.  You however cannot create one like you do now, as a local variable.  It will be garbage collected too soon.